# CookSwing - Getting id of a tag

Tags: java, swing

I wrote a XML file containing the following tag:

```
<textfield columns="20" id="amount" />
```

This tag refers to a textfield. For getting text typed into the textfield, i'm using the following code:'

```
JTextField amount = (JTextField) cookSwing.getId("virgolacifre").object;  
String amountString = amount.getText();
```

I would like to obtain something similar, but in an "automatic" way. I'll explain: in this way I've to know how many textfield are present on my xml file and I have to create as many `JTextField` as there are tags. If I wanted to edit the xml file by adding a tag, I should also change my java code. Is there any way to obtain something like this?

```
for each <textfield columns="20" id="abcdefg" />    
 JTextField abcdefg = new JTextField();
```

Thank you in advance